# How do I make a column in MySQL which value increases automatically

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose that there are some rows with numeric values. Is it possible to increase or decrease the values automatically?

Example: (column name: **Token**)

```
Token
1234
4567
9521
```

After "x" seconds, it will be automatically:

```
Token
1234 + x
4567 + x
9521 + x
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Rather than update the database values on a recurring basis, why not programmatically calculate the result at time needed?

Comment: I want to create random token generator which will expire automatically, that's why I need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a view, assuming that you have the time when the token was created:

```
create view v_t
    select . . .,
           (token + timestampdiff(second, tokenCreateTime, now())) as token
    from t;
```

You do not want to do this by updating the database -- you'll need to update all the rows every second.  That won't leave much processing power to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,dt INT NOT NULL, starting_val INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),1234),(2,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),4567),(3,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),9521);

...

SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-dt+starting_val x FROM my_table;
+----+------------+--------------+------+
| id | dt         | starting_val | x    |
+----+------------+--------------+------+
|  1 | 1485107095 |         1234 | 1284 |
|  2 | 1485107095 |         4567 | 4617 |
|  3 | 1485107095 |         9521 | 9571 |
+----+------------+--------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, you can do same thing using more efficient methodology. But if you are strict to do that you can use MySQL's [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) which was added in MySQL 5.1.6.

```
CREATE EVENT `updateEverySecond` ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 SECOND
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT 'Optional comment...'
    DO 
BEGIN
UPDATE my_table SET token = token + 1
END
```

Comment: Thanks, I am gonna try it... :)

Comment: You're welcome. Try it and share your results & ideas with us.